# Is there a way that I can go up an ADT list? (bubblesorting an ADT list)

Tags: c, list

(1 mo into learning c) I've been learning about making/using ADT lists and learned the basic functions(used for making ADT lists) like 'count', 'concatenate', 'insert' and etc. And i had an (online course)assignment that required me to bubblesort an ADT list.

So I kinda implemented what I knew about bubblesorting an array to the ADT list. Normally bubblesorting an array looks like this:

```
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n) { //int n = numb of elements in the array
    int i, j;  
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)  
        if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])  
            swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]); //assuming 'swap(a,b);' swaps the two elements
    }
}
```

So simply i 'just' implemented the modified 'swap' function and that was what i did like the below code. (I couldn't really think of a better method, tried anything what i could do)

```
typedef struct list { int data; struct list *next; } list;

...//some portion of the code fills/links the nodes

void bubblesort(list* p) {
    list* pn = p->next;
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < SIZE - j - 1; j++) {
            if (p->data > pn->data) // Exception ERR here
                datSwap(p, pn); // just swaps (only)the data portion of the two nodes(in ADT lists)
            p = pn;
            pn = pn->next;
            if (pn == NULL)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure this code isn't pretty and it certainly doesn't work(Exception thrown: read access violation. 'pn' was nullptr.).

When I looked into the problem I thought that in normal situations when using arrays(the 1st code) 'j' used in arrays like 'arr[j+1]' would reset to the starting point(arr[0]) once the for loop was done, but ADT lists not having such 'positions(?)' ended up not resetting the position to the beginning(or to the head) which caused the 'np' to be NULL. So in my theory either the 'p' needed to be reset to the head by reversing up the list(which to my knowledge I don't know how to) or the bubblesort() function needs to be redesigned.

So, my question is...

Can I change the 'pointer of the ADT list'(Am i phrasing this right?) which is at the tail to the head? Image for explanation(idk whether people can understand what i'm saying or not so i included an image)
[image]

I know how to progress into a list like the following code which prints a list using 'p = p->data' like below but i want to know if i can do it the opposite way or not
typedef struct list { int data; struct list *next; } list;

```
...//some portion of the code fills/links the nodes

void printList(list* p) {
    int i = 0;
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%d", p->data);
        p = p->next;
        if (p == NULL)
            break;
        else
            printf(" : "); i++; if (i % 10 == 0 && i > 0) { printf("\n"); }
    }
}
```

if not, how can i change/improve the 'bubblesort' function to sort the lists?

Thank you and if I said something wrong please correct me.

Comment: Do you want a circular list, where the end points to the beginning? Or is this a sorting question? It's honestly hard to tell because you've written so much and so little of it makes sense.

Comment: @Maxjo In any case this function declaration void bubblesort(list* p) ; is wrong because the pointer to the head node is passed by value. So changing the parameter p within the function will not influence on the original pointer to the head node passed to the function as an argument.

Comment: @brothir Sorry I can't really think how to question this in my mind, it's a sorting question

Comment: @VladfromMoscow then there is no way of returning the pointer to the head without exiting the function?

Comment: @Maxjo You can pass the pointer for example by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reformulate the inner loop to iterate over `p` list from the first to "before last" element.

```
for (list *j = p; j->next; j = j->next)
    if (j->data > j->next->data)
        datSwap(j, j->next);
```